# Save file using timestamp

Tags: android, timestamp

I am trying to save a file using a timestamp as the name. I can save the file no problem when I name it myself but when I try to use a timestamp it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();

        File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                 + ts);
        try {
            newxmlfile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
        }

        FileOutputStream fileos = null;
        try {
            fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");
        }
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT(SOLVED): I changed the line below and it saved the file using the timestamp as an xml file.

```
File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                 ,ts + ".xml");
```

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: -1 for not defining "doesn't work"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are creating you file with an invalid path.

When you doing the string concatination:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + ts
```

... you add your time stamp `123456`to the file path (something like) `/mnt/sdcard`. And you end up with an invalid path like:

```
/mnt/sdcard14571747181
```

(And you havn't got access to write to that file since it isn't inside the external dir.)

Either you add a file separator yourself or you create the file with:

```
File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ts);
                                                                    ^^
                                                                the change
```